# How to get aws_attributes programatically in PySpark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Is there a way to retrieve the aws_attributes of the cluster running PySpark/Databricks programmatically?

Specifically, I'd like to get the information about which region the cluster is running so I can output to the same-region S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by calling [Cluster Get REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#get) - it will return JSON including the `aws_attributes`.  Something like this:

```py
import requests
ctx = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()
host_name = ctx.tags().get("browserHostName").get()
host_token = "your_PAT_token"
cluster_id = ctx.tags().get("clusterId").get()

response = requests.get(
    f'https://{host_name}/api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id={cluster_id}',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'}
  ).json()
aws_info = response['aws_attributes']
```